# Magento 2 set and access variables between controllers

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, session, registry

I have a problem with storing and accesing variables accross controllers.

i have controller 1 there i set variable ( tried registry and session )
in block of that controller i have both and registry and session variables..
then we are visiting product page and from there we go to controller 2 both session and registry variables are empty.

tried following sessions catalog and persisent

any other way to pass variables between controllers ?

so the flow is:

Controller1(set variable) -> Block1 -> Product view page -> Controller2(acces variable) -> Block2

Comment: why don't you send the variable along with value in URL param

Comment: that's an option but for that i will have to change theme templates, which is not a wanted option since i want to keep it as module only.